# How to call a template class from a Qt designer class

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a template class as following. I am new to this template concept.

```
template<class T>
class tem_class
{

private:
    T obj;
public:
    tem_class();
    void set_values(T x);
    T disp_fun();

};
```

Then I tried to invoke this class in Widget class.

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
       int a,b;
        a=5;
        tem_class<int> obj2 ;
        obj2.set_values(a);
        b = obj2.disp_fun();
    }
```

But I am getting following errors.
 error: undefined reference to `tem_class<int>::tem_class()
 error: undefined reference to`tem_class::set_values(int)
error: undefined reference to `tem_class::disp_fun()
 error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Where are the definitions of `tem_class()`, `set_values()` and `disp_func()`?

Comment: template <class T>
tem_class<T>::tem_class()
{
   
}

template <class T>
void tem_class<T>::set_values(T x)
{
   
   obj = x;
}

template <class T>
T tem_class<T>::disp_fun()
{
 
    return obj;
}

Comment: I mean where are they physically defined - you haven't placed them into a cpp file, have you?

Comment: yeah.in cpp file

Comment: in that case that is your problem. Basically move them into the .h file and you should be fine. The dupe I linked has some additional information about defining template members.

Comment: ok..I understood.now I palced defintion in .h file. Thanks